# Circular graph with many nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have a simple circular graph with N nodes. However N could be arbitrarily large, so I use an ellipsis between nodes. I use the following code:
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning, calc}

\definecolor{lavander}{cmyk}{0,0.48,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}
\def\lav{lavander!90}
\def\oran{orange!30}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
   peer/.style={draw,circle,violet,bottom color=red, top color= white, text=violet, minimum width=25pt},
   superpeer/.style={draw, circle,  left color=burntorange, text=violet, minimum width=25pt},
   point/.style = {fill=black,inner sep=1pt, circle, minimum width=5pt,align=right,rotate=60},
   forward edge/.style={->, >=stealth, shorten >=0pt, thick, color=blue},
   }

\def \n {8}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm, semithick]
\node[superpeer] (A) at ({360/\n * (1 - 1)}:3.5){$0$};
\node[peer]         (B)  at ({360/\n * (2 - 1)}:3.5){$1$};
\node[peer]         (C)  at ({360/\n * (3 - 1)}:3.5){$2$};
\node[peer]         (D)   at ({360/\n * (4 - 1)}:2.5){$3$};
\node[point] (p1)  at ({360/\n * (4.5 - 1)}:2.5){};
\node[point] (p2)  at ({360/\n * (4.6- 1)}:2.5){};  
\node[point] (p3)  at ({360/\n * (4.7 - 1)}:2.5){};
\node[peer] (E) at ({360/\n * (7 - 1)}:3.5) {$N$};
\path (A) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[]{$\lambda_{01}, \mu_{01}$} (B);
\path (B) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[]   {$\lambda_{12}, \mu_{12}$} (C);
\path (C) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{23}, \mu_{23}$}(D);
\path (A) edge [color=blue, bend left=20, above, sloped] node[]{$\lambda_{0N}, \mu_{0N}$} (E);
\path (B) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{10}, \mu_{10}$}(A);
\path (C) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{21}, \mu_{21}$}(B);
\path (D) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{32}, \mu_{32}$}(C);
\path (E) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, below, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{{N-1},N}, \mu_{{N-1},N}$}(A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result however is not great. The circle is hardly symmetrical, and the ellipsis are a sore spot by themselves. Can someone aid me in "professionalising! this figure? Thanks!

Comment: In its current form your example does not compile for me as it seems ti require some TikZ libraries. Could you please expand your code to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? This would lower the barrier to work with your code and therefore increase chances a lot that someone is willing to help you find a solution. Also at least an image of the current output would be nice to see how it looks like at the moment.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: I have managed to give a MWE. Thanks!

Comment: This example is far from minimal. Your color definitions and most of your options are not necessary for your problem. Also in the first edge the node is missing a closed bracket. That's why this does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An solution based on your code. This could serves as a starting point for further simplification of your code. The unsymmetrical comes from the fact that `\n=8` defined in the code, but insufficient points (only 5) were given.  The correction is to add extra points A1,B1 and C1 and assign their locations properly. This solution also suggests `foreach loop` to simplify the code.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning, calc}

\definecolor{lavander}{cmyk}{0,0.48,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}
\def\lav{lavander!90}
\def\oran{orange!30}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
   peer/.style={draw,circle,violet,bottom color=red, top color= white, text=violet, minimum width=25pt},
   superpeer/.style={draw, circle,  left color=burntorange, text=violet, minimum width=25pt},
   point/.style = {fill=black,inner sep=1pt, circle, minimum width=5pt,align=right,rotate=60},
%   forward edge/.style={->, >=stealth, shorten >=0pt, thick, color=blue},
   }

\def \n {8}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm, semithick]
\node[superpeer]    (A)   at ({360/\n * (1 - 1)}:2.5){$3$};
\node[peer]         (B)   at ({360/\n * (2 - 1)}:2.5){$2$};
\node[peer]         (C)   at ({360/\n * (3 - 1)}:2.5){$1$};
\node[peer]         (D)   at ({360/\n * (4 - 1)}:2.5){$N$};
\node[peer]         (E)   at ({360/\n * (5 - 1)}:2.5){$7$};
\node[peer]         (A1)  at ({360/\n * (6 - 1)}:2.5){$6$};
\node[peer]         (B1)  at ({360/\n * (7 - 1)}:2.5){$5$};
\node[peer]         (C1)  at ({360/\n * (8 - 1)}:2.5){$4$};
\node[point] (p1)  at ({360/\n * (4.4 - 1)}:2.5){};
\node[point] (p2)  at ({360/\n * (4.5 - 1)}:2.5){};  
\node[point] (p3)  at ({360/\n * (4.6 - 1)}:2.5){};


\path (A) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[]{$\lambda_{23}, \mu_{23}$} (B);
\path (B) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{32}, \mu_{32}$}(A);

\path (B) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{21}, \mu_{21}$} (C);
\path (C) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{12}, \mu_{12}$}(B);

\path (C) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{N1}, \mu_{N1}$}(D);
\path (D) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{N1}, \mu_{N1}$}(C);

\path (A1) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[]{$\lambda_{67}, \mu_{67}$} (E);
\path (E) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, below, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{76}, \mu_{76}$}(A1);

\path (A) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{34}, \mu_{34}$} (C1);
\path (C1) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{43}, \mu_{43}$}(A);

\path (A1) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{65}, \mu_{65}$} (B1);
\path (B1) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{56}, \mu_{56}$}(A1);

\path (C1) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{45}, \mu_{45}$}(B1);
\path (B1) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[] {$\lambda_{54}, \mu_{54}$}(C1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Simplified code via `foreach loop`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning, calc}

\definecolor{lavander}{cmyk}{0,0.48,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}
\def\lav{lavander!90}
\def\oran{orange!30}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
   peer/.style={draw,circle,violet,bottom color=red, top color= white, text=violet, minimum width=25pt},
   superpeer/.style={draw, circle,  left color=burntorange, text=violet, minimum width=25pt},
   point/.style = {fill=black,inner sep=1pt, circle, minimum width=5pt,align=right,rotate=60},
%   forward edge/.style={->, >=stealth, shorten >=0pt, thick, color=blue},
   }

\def \n {8}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm, semithick]

\node[peer]          (C)   at ({360/\n * (3 - 1)}:2.5){$1$};
\node[peer]          (B)   at ({360/\n * (2 - 1)}:2.5){$2$};
\node[superpeer]     (A)   at ({360/\n * (1 - 1)}:2.5){$3$};
\node[peer]         (C1)   at ({360/\n * (8 - 1)}:2.5){$4$};
\node[peer]         (B1)   at ({360/\n * (7 - 1)}:2.5){$5$};
\node[peer]         (A1)   at ({360/\n * (6 - 1)}:2.5){$6$};
\node[peer]         (E)    at ({360/\n * (5 - 1)}:2.5){$7$};
\node[peer]         (D)    at ({360/\n * (4 - 1)}:2.5){$N$};

\node[point] (p1)  at ({360/\n * (4.4 - 1)}:2.5){};
\node[point] (p2)  at ({360/\n * (4.5 - 1)}:2.5){};  
\node[point] (p3)  at ({360/\n * (4.6 - 1)}:2.5){};

\foreach \s/\e/\f/\t in {D/C/N/1,C/B/1/2,B/A/2/3,A/C1/3/4,C1/B1/4/5,B1/A1/5/6,A1/E/6/7}
{\path (\s) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[]{\tiny $\lambda_{\f\t},\mu_{\f\t}$} (\e);
 \path (\e) edge [color=blue, bend right=20, above, sloped] node[]{\tiny $\lambda_{\t\f},\mu_{\t\f}$} (\s);
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I misunderstood you. You don't actually want to draw `N` nodes but draw a general diagram. In this case, the polar coordinate notation `(angle:radius)` I am using below is your friend and should answer all your questions.

I have a starting point here. (note the size of the example). You just have to add your style options and your specific labels now.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def \n {8}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (node0) at (0:3) {0};
\def\lasti{0} %fixing bug for older tikz versions
\foreach[
    evaluate=\i as \angle using (\i)*360/(\n+1),
    remember=\i as \lasti (initialy 0)
] \i in {1,...,\n} {
    \node (node\i) at (\angle:3) {\i};
    \draw (node\i) edge[<-,bend left=20] 
        node[pos=0.5,sloped,above] {$\lambda_{\i}$} 
    (node\lasti);
    \draw (node\i) edge[->,bend right=20] 
            node [pos=0.5,sloped,above] {$\lambda_{\i}$} 
    (node\lasti);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]